# Merge two scenes in Three.js and React Three Fiber

Tags: three.js, shader, react-three-fiber, rendertarget

I’ve been dedicating my free time for the past 2 months to learn Three.JS and R3F, at least the basics to add details on my projects. Unfortunately, I can’t say I’ve progressed a lot, I am stuck with the following:

**I have two scenes, the first have a background** that simulates lava lamps and **the other scene has a JPG image (a screenshot of the lava lamp background) as a texture to which I apply a displacement** (the classic wave/ripple that follows the mouse). I would like to know **how to use the first scene as a texture for the second one to apply the displacement effect** instead of apply to a simple JPG image texture.

Asking for help wasn’t the first thing I did :P. I was trying to do it with render targets and composing an effect, but I couldn’t. There’s something I’m doing wrong and I don’t know what it is, it’s very frustrating.

I create the scenes in StackBlitz for demostration with random colors:

[Code of scene with the lava lamp background](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yvahyp?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FScene.tsx)
[Code of scene with the image and displacement](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-cqzudz?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FScene.tsx)
[And this is what I been trying with render targets](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-amvfbq?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FScene.tsx)

I don’t want to bother too much, if you can guide me a bit or if you know of any example, I would be super grateful.

Thanks guys!